# How to use custom "abstract" route in emberjs

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, ember-cli

I have started with ember and ember-cli. Ember-cli is somewhat different than Ember shown in most of the tutorials.

I can not understand what do I need to do to inherit my own custom "Route".
For example I made a file:

`authenticated.coffee`

and in it:

`AuthenticatedRoute = Ember.Route.extend`

Now I want to do the following:

- make a new file called secret.coffee with:

  `SacretRoute = AuthenticatedRoute.extend`

The best I got so far is `import AuthenticatedRoute from '../routes/authenticated'` which says that it included the file but says that it can not do .extend on undefined.

I do not quite understand it and I have googled all around so please if there is an answer somewhere please you can politely give me a link.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with `coffee` script but have you may have forgotten to export `AuthenticaedRoute`.

And also suggestion from stefanpenner who is creator of `ember-cli`. Don't hold reference of your extended `route` or `controller` just export it as

```
export default Ember.Route.extend();
```

Comment: I can not use export default because coffeescript wont compile it, I can use `` around it but if I have more then a line of code I use `export default ...Route` at the end.